# How can I remove a marker from map with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Each marker has a "state" if the state is "aceite", "concluido" or "em avaliação" it will show on the map, however if the state is "recusado" I don't want it to show in the map. Here is the code:

```
$.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    //identificação do tipo de marcador que deve aparecer de acordo com o estado da ignição
    var ignicao;

    if (item.estado == "aceite") {
      ignicao = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "/icons/aceite.png",
        iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
      });
    } else {
      if (item.estado == "em avaliação") {
        ignicao = L.icon({
          iconUrl: "/icons/emAvaliacao.png",
          iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
        });
      } else {
        if (item.estado == "concluido") {
          ignicao = L.icon({
            iconUrl: "/icons/concluido.png",
            iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
          });
        } else {
          if (item.estado == "recusado") {
            //don't show it on the map
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I've already tried using "removeFrom" and "remove", but I get an error saying that it's not a function. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That's missing code. How are you instantiating and adding the markers? Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teresa! It's nice to see colleagues from Brazil here :P

I found two possible options for that. Assuming you have a marker variable called `markerLayer`:

1) Remove the marker layer: `map.removeLayer(markerLayer)`

2) Keep the marker layer and just "hide" the icon: `markerLayer.setOpacity(0)`

Take a look on the fiddle I wrote with a button example: https://jsfiddle.net/diogocosta/jmq8h2wr/6/

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you! I used the first option, it worked just fine! Keep up the good work